# FOR JSON queries in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, for-json

I have a problem in SQL Server 2016 with `FOR JSON` queries. The output is cut in a specified number of characters.

for example I use this code and it's result is cut to 2033 characters:

```
SELECT  
    [id] as id
    ,[id] as dmn
    ,[engin] as engin
    ,[page] as page
    ,[name] as page_name
    ,[lastedite] as lastedite
    ,[deleted] as deleted
    ,[MimeType] as MimeType
    ,[cache] as cache
    ,[userid] as userid
    ,[ownerid] as ownerid 
FROM  
    test 
FOR JSON PATH
```

Comment: Are you copying this from a result set in SQL Server Management Studio? Because results are always trimmed to about the size your mention.

Comment: Which field is cut? how do you observe it? What if you wrap a LENGTH function around it?

Comment: yes,This happens in different fields based on the number of characters